# Migrating VMs in VMware Player to VMware Workstation

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation

Is there a way to migrate the VMs created in VMware Player to VMware Workstation ?

My PC had VMware Player previously on my personal laptop, and I have 3 VMs created. I recently installed VMware Workstation on my office laptop, and would like to migrate the VM images (disk-image, with the metadata) from Player to Workstation. Can it be done ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No migration necessary, simply copy over the whole folder for each VM and open the .vmx